# An Image will not inherit height when in Chrome but will in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

So I'm developing a website for someone and the layout works perfectly in Firefox, with the image inheriting height for the table-cell it's in but in Chrome it's setting it's height to 100% of the actual image size.

Here's some sample images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbATs.jpg

The first one is chrome, the second Firefox. I'm currently only applying the CSS to the first image.

Here is the relevant CSS:

On the image:

```
  vertical-align:bottom;width:100%;height:100%
```

On the table cell:

```
#navbar-image{
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:#FF8B08;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:17.5%;
    height:10%;
    max-height:10%;
}
```

The row CSS:

```
#nav-bar{
    height:10%;
    max-height:10%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #060606;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:#FF8B08;
    background-color:#252525;
    border-spacing: 0px; 
    position:relative;
    left:25%;
    top:0%;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/yrzccn3j/
Any ideas?

Comment: have your tried adding `max-height: 100%` as CSS on the image?

Comment: I just did, and it has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you have this code in the `<img>` tag:

```
img {
     vertical-align:bottom;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
}
```

You should to change height property like this:

```
img {
     vertical-align:bottom;
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
}
```

This works in all browsers, and preserve proportions of the images.

Comment: I do not want to preserve the proportions of the image as that leaves blank space around the image. I need it to stretch to the height of the box.